# Keras/Tensorflow GridSearchCV on Spark cluster

Tags: python, apache-spark, tensorflow, keras, grid-search

I am trying to execute a Grid Search on a Spark cluster. For this reason, I am running `nohup ./spark_python_shell.sh > output.log &` at my `bash` shell to ignite the Spark cluster and I also get my python script running (see below `spark-submit \ --master yarn 'dnn_grid_search.py'`):

```
    SPARK_HOME=/u/users/******/spark-2.3.0 \
    Q_CORE_LOC=/u/users/******/q-core \
    ENV=local \
    HIVE_HOME=/usr/hdp/current/hive-client \
    SPARK2_HOME=/u/users/******/spark-2.3.0 \
    HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/etc/hadoop/conf \
    HIVE_CONF_DIR=/etc/hive/conf \
    HDFS_PREFIX=hdfs:// \
    PYTHONPATH=/u/users/******/q-core/python-lib:/u/users/******/three-queues/python-lib:/u/users/******/pyenv/prod_python_libs/lib/python2.7/site-packages/:$PYTHON_PATH \
    YARN_HOME=/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-yarn-client \
    SPARK_DIST_CLASSPATH=$(hadoop classpath):$(yarn classpath):/etc/hive/conf/hive-site.xml \
    PYSPARK_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python2.7 \
    QQQ_LOC=/u/users/******/three-queues \
    spark-submit \
    --master yarn 'dnn_grid_search.py' \
    --executor-memory 10g \
    --num-executors 8 \
    --executor-cores 10 \
    --conf spark.port.maxRetries=80 \
    --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=False \
    --conf spark.default.parallelism=6000 \
    --conf spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=6000 \
    --principal ************************ \
    --queue default \
    --name lets_get_starting \
    --keytab /u/users/******/.******.keytab \
    --driver-memory 10g
```

In this `dnn_grid_search.py` python script there is the following source code which tries to connect the Grid Search with the Spark cluster:

```
# Create the 'Keras' classifier
# 'keras_model' is a function which returns the 'Keras' model which I built
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier
classifier = KerasClassifier(build_fn=keras_model, verbose=0)

# Spark configuration
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
conf = SparkConf()
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)

# Execute grid search - using spark_sklearn library
from spark_sklearn import GridSearchCV
classifiers_grid = GridSearchCV(sc, estimator=classifier, param_grid=parameters, scoring=custom_scorer, cv=train_valid_predefined_split,n_jobs=-1)
classifiers_grid.fit(X, y)
```

When I am running the python script then I am getting an error at the line `classifiers_grid.fit(X, y)` which is the following:

```
ImportError: No module named keras.wrappers.scikit_learn
```

or in quite greater detail (but without including everything because it is too long) is the following:

```
18/10/23 12:53:38 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 2.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 2, *******.*******.com, executor 2, partition 2, PROCESS_LOCAL, 42479 bytes)
18/10/23 12:53:38 WARN scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1, *******.*******.com, executor 2): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/u/applic/data/hdfs12/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/*******/appcache/application_1539785180345_30553/container_e126_1539785180345_30553_01_000003/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 216, in main
    func, profiler, deserializer, serializer = read_command(pickleSer, infile)
  File "/u/applic/data/hdfs12/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/*******/appcache/application_1539785180345_30553/container_e126_1539785180345_30553_01_000003/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 60, in read_command
    command = serializer.loads(command.value)
  File "/u/applic/data/hdfs12/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/*******/appcache/application_1539785180345_30553/container_e126_1539785180345_30553_01_000003/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 562, in loads
    return pickle.loads(obj)
ImportError: No module named keras.wrappers.scikit_learn

        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:298)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRunner.scala:438)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRunner.scala:421)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:252)
        at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
        at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.foreach(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
        at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:59)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:104)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:310)
        at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.to(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:302)
        at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.toBuffer(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:289)
        at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.toArray(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1$$anonfun$12.apply(RDD.scala:939)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1$$anonfun$12.apply(RDD.scala:939)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2067)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2067)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

**How can I use GridSearchCV with Keras models on a Spark cluster** (in general or specifically with the `spark_sklearn` library)**?**

Comment: This means that Keras is not installed on the worker nodes. It has to be either distributed along with the task (hard to do it right, unless the cluster is homogeneous), or preinstall on the workers.

Comment: @user10465355, thank you for your answer. I am not exactly aware of the meaning of 'workers' on Spark but I can say that apparently `Keras` is installed (not on the workers though?) since the object `classifier` is a `Keras` model.

Comment: Just because Keras is installed on the driver node (here the machine you use for submit, as you seem to use the client mode), it doesn't mean it is installed on the cluster.

Comment: _meaning of 'workers'_ - the nodes, on which your application is executed, when submitted to the cluster.

Comment: @user10465355, ok, so the problem is with `Keras` because it is not installed on the workers and because also it is the one which I want to use on them? (For example, why the error does not happen with other libraries which I am using?).